# Problem with counting MAX value of distinct column

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have a table called "levels" in Amazon Athena that includes columns called "user", "levelstarted" and "levelcount". The table looks like that:

`+------+---------------+--------------+
| user | levelstarted  | startedcount |
+------+---------------+--------------+
| A    | 0050          | 2            |
| A    | 0051          | 1            |
| A    | 0052          | 3            |
| B    | 0030          | 1            |
| B    | 0031          | 2            |
| B    | 0032          | 5            |
| C    | 0010          | 6            |
| C    | 0011          | 3            |
| C    | 0012          | 3            |
+------+---------------+--------------+`

For each user I want to find a highest level started and how many times player has started the level. I hope to get results that look like that:

`+------+----------------+----------------+
| user | highestlevel | | startedcount | |
+------+----------------+----------------+
| A    | 0052           | 3              |
| B    | 0032           | 5              |
| C    | 0012           | 3              |
+------+----------------+----------------+`

Finding highest started level works just fine:

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT user as payer,
 MAX(levelstarted) as levelstarted
FROM "levels"
GROUP BY user, startedcount
```

But when I add started count I get duplicate users in the results:

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT user as payer,
 MAX(levelstarted) as levelstarted,
 startedcount
FROM "levels"
GROUP BY user, levelcount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Athena/Presto you can use the [`max_by`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max_by) function to find a value associated with the max value of a column:

```
SELECT
  user,
  MAX(levelstarted) AS highestlevel,
  MAX_BY(startedcount, levelstarted) AS startedcount
FROM (VALUES ('A', '0050', 2),
             ('A', '0051', 1),
             ('A', '0052', 3),
             ('B', '0030', 1),
             ('B', '0031', 2),
             ('B', '0032', 5),
             ('C', '0010', 6),
             ('C', '0011', 3),
             ('C', '0012', 3)
) AS v (user, levelstarted, startedcount)
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY user
```